# Navigation Component pass args type BigDecimal

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation, android-safe-args

As the title described, I want to pass `BigDecimal` type argument between the fragments while navigation. But I can't find the support of `BigDecimal` type.

Here is the link of the supported types from google document [support types](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-pass-data#supported_argument_types)

Any way to achieve it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the [BigDecimal docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/math/BigDecimal), `BigDecimal` extends [`Number`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Number) which implements `Serializable`, which means it is supported just like any other `Serializable` type in Navigation, as per the table you linked.

```
app:argType="java.math.BigDecimal"
```